# Is it possible to style truck specific road signs with custom YAML styling instead of a truckonlytile png layer?

Tags: javascript, here-api

Currently I am working with the v3.1 API of Here maps and use a vector map (as described in [this guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/vector.html)). 
On top of that, I use the truckonlytile layer to display truck specific road signs. This works fine.

As a next step the client wants to style the truck road signs so that it matches the corporate identity.
Is this possible with the custom YAML styling? Or is there another way how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, now you want to change the color/pattern of the truck road sign ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no other way to display truck road signs.
Road signs will be part of YAML style soon.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Is there a feature roadmap available somewhere where I can read more about upcoming features?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any publicly available feature roadmap.